# How to split records into different streams, from one topic to different streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have a single source CSV file containing records of different sizes that pushes every record into one source topic. I want to split the records into different KStreams/KTables from that source topic. I have a pipeline for one table load, where I am pushing the record from the source topic into stream1 in delimited format and then pushing the records into another stream in AVRO format which is then pushed into JDBC sink connector that pushes the record into MySQL database. The pipeline needs to be the same. But I wanted to push records of different tables into one source topic and then split the records into the different streams as per one value. Is this possible? I tried searching for ways to do that but could not. Can I improve the pipeline somehow too or use KTable instead of KStreams or any other modifications?

My current flow -
one source CSV file (`source.csv`) -> source topic (name - sourcetopic containing test1 records) -> stream 1 (delimited value format) -> stream 2 (as AVRO value format) -> end topic (name - `sink-db-test1`) -> JDBC sink connector -> MySQL DB (name - `test1`)

I have a different MySQL table `test2` with a different schema and the records for this table are also present in `source.csv` file. Since the schema is different I cannot follow the current pipeline of `test1` to insert data into the `test2` table.

Example -
in CSV source file,

`line 1 - 9,atm,mun,ronaldo
 line 2- 10,atm,mun,bravo,num2
 line 3 - 11,atm,sign,bravo,sick`

here in this example, the value under which it is to be split is `column 4` (`ronaldo` or `bravo`)
all these data should be loaded into `table 1`, `table 2`, `table 3` respectively
The key is the column 4.

`if col4==ronaldo, go to table 1
 if col4==bravo and col3==mun, go to table 2
 if col4==bravo and col3 ==sign go to table 3`

I am very new to Kafka, started Kafka development from the previous week.

Comment: Sorry, I hide my answer cause it seems not relevant, cause you have to write a Kafka Streams application to read from input topic to different topics. You should send data from different tables to different topics, not in different topic's partitions as you stated in comment. Why would you want to send each type to different partition of one topic.

Comment: I am getting all data in a single source CSV file. From there I have to split the records and then do it. So currently I am having one source topic and it reads the data from the source CSV file and then inserts into the database. The source file is one so I guess only one topic can be used to read from that source file.

Comment: So the flow should be like - one source CSV file containing all data -> split the data into different end topics for different MySQLA tables.

Comment: understood, my solution is to write a separated Kafka Streams application to read from the input topic and then apply branching logic based on some custom logic

Comment: Ok. The Kafka stream can directly pick up data as per the schema mentioned while creating the stream. The problem arises when we have data of different tables but with same columns. I tried with records of different column sizes and I am able to split. But the problem arises when I am having same column size for different table data.

Comment: So your problem is when you have a record, and multiple tables have same column size correspond with this record and you do not know which table to send to?

Comment: Yes. The only thing I know is I know the data that is present and it has one certain field that determines which table it should go to. This is the reason why I want to implement the splitting of records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211539/discussion-between-tuyen-luong-and-sanjay-nayak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a separated Kafka Streams application to split records from the input topic to different KStream or output topics using [`KStream#branch()` operator](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations):

```
KStream<K, V>[] branches = streamsBuilder.branch(
        (key, value) -> {filter logic for topic 1 here},
        (key, value) -> {filter logic for topic 2 here},
        (key, value) -> true//get all messages for this branch
);

// KStream branches[0] records for logic 1
// KStream branches[1] records for logic 2
// KStream branches[2] records for logic 3
```

Or you could manually branch your KStream like this:

```
KStream<K, V> inputKStream = streamsBuilder.stream("your_input_topic", Consumed.with(keySerde, valueSerdes));

inputKStream
        .filter((key, value) -> {filter logic for topic 1 here})
        .to("your_1st_output_topic");

inputKStream
        .filter((key, value) -> {filter logic for topic 2 here})
        .to("your_2nd_output_topic");
...
```

Comment: So for this do I need to write a custom source connector? I am currently using the SpoolDir connector (SpoolDirLineDelimitedSourceConnector). I am trying to add some configurations to that. If I send data of a particular type into a particular partition and then load the streams as per the partition, can something like this be considered or possible?

Comment: `streamsBuilder.branch(..)` is deprecated since version 2.8. New syntax: `var branches = streamsBuilder.split(Name.as("prefix-")).branch((key, value) -> condition1, Branched.withFunction(kstream -> kstream, "branch1")) .branch((key, value) -> condition2, Branched.withConsumer(kstream -> kstream)); var branch1KStream = branches.get("prefix-branch1");`

You can finalize the construction of branches with `.defaultBranch()` or `noDefaultBranch()` depending on if you want to a default branch for the messages not intercepted or not.

Comment: The key of defaultBranch will be "prefix-0" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to split the data and used KSQL for the approach that I am sharing below.
1. An input stream is created with `value_format='JSON'` and a column `payload` as `STRING` 
2. The payload will contain the whole record as a `STRING`
3. The record is then split into different streams using `LIKE` operator in the `WHERE` clause while putting the payload into different streams as per the requirement. Here I have used `SPLIT` operator of KSQL to get the records from payload that are in comma-delimited format